# neo4j.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable Connection to 127.0.0.1:7687 closed without handshake response

Tags: python, docker, neo4j

I keep getting

```
neo4j.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: Couldn't connect to localhost:7687 (resolved to ()):
Connection to 127.0.0.1:7687 closed without handshake response
```

without a proper explanation why the service is considered to be unavailable. I am using the official neoj4:latest docker image as outlined below. The check for the port to be available is positive and the web environment works fine at port 7474 happily connecting to port 7687. Just the python driver complains.

Interestingly the CI test works of github fine - just the test in my Jenkins environment on a local ubuntu server reports the problem.

**What might be the cause of this misbehavior?**

**My Environment**
Python Version: Python 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0]
Driver Version: Name: neo4j Version: 5.10.0
Summary: Neo4j Bolt driver for Python
Server Version and Edition: neo4j:latest docker images
Operating System:Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

Issue to be addressed: https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pyCEURmake/issues/84.
You'll  also find the source code of the snippets below in the above project.

**Script to start neo4j**
see https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pyCEURmake/blob/main/scripts/neo4j

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# WF 2023-07-15

# Stop and remove any existing Neo4j container
docker stop neo4j-instance
docker rm neo4j-instance

# Run the Neo4j container
# https://neo4j.com/developer/docker-run-neo4j/
docker run -d --name neo4j-instance \
  --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
  --env NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/password \
  --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data \
  neo4j:latest

# Function to display a progress bar
display_progress() {
  local progress=$1
  local max_progress=$2
  local bar_length=40
  local filled_length=$((progress * bar_length / max_progress))
  local empty_length=$((bar_length - filled_length))

  # Build the progress bar string
  local bar="["
  bar+="$(printf "%${filled_length}s" | tr ' ' '#')"
  bar+="$(printf "%${empty_length}s" | tr ' ' '-')"
  bar+="]"

  # Print the progress bar
  printf "\r%s %d%%" "$bar" $((progress * 100 / max_progress))
}

# Wait for Neo4j to start
progress=0
max_progress=20
sleep_duration=0.5
while [ "$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Running}}' neo4j-instance 2>/dev/null)" != "true" ] && [ $progress -lt $max_progress ]; do
  display_progress $progress $max_progress
  ((progress++))
  sleep $sleep_duration
done

# Clear the progress bar line
printf "\r%${COLUMNS}s\r"

if [ "$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Running}}' neo4j-instance 2>/dev/null)" == "true" ]; then
  echo "Neo4j is running."
else
  echo "Failed to start Neo4j."
fi

# Display the logs to check the status
docker logs neo4j-instance
```

**neo4j wrapper class**

```py
import argparse
import json
import os
import re
import requests
import socket
import sys

from typing import List, Optional
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
from neo4j.exceptions import ServiceUnavailable, AuthError, ConfigurationError


class Neo4j:
    """
    Neo4j wrapper class
    """
    def __init__(self,host:str="localhost",bolt_port:int=7687,auth=("neo4j", "password"),encrypted:bool=False):
        """
        constructor
        """
        self.driver = None
        self.error = None
        self.host=host
        self.bolt_port=bolt_port
        self.encrypted=encrypted
        try:
            uri=f"bolt://{host}:{bolt_port}"      
            if not Neo4j.is_port_available(host,bolt_port):
                raise ValueError(f"port at {uri} not available")
            self.driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=auth,encrypted=encrypted)
        except (ServiceUnavailable, AuthError, ConfigurationError) as e:
            self.error = e
         
    @classmethod   
    def is_port_available(cls,host, port:int)->bool:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.settimeout(1)  # 1 Second Timeout
        try:
            sock.connect((host, port))
        except socket.error:
            return False
        return True

    def close(self):
        if self.driver is not None:
            self.driver.close()

@dataclass
class Volume:
    """
    Represents a volume with its attributes.
    """

    acronym: str
    title: str
    loctime: str
    editors: List['Editor'] = field(default_factory=list)

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_data):
        """
        Create a Volume instance from JSON data.

        Args:
            json_data (dict): The JSON data representing the volume.

        Returns:
            Volume: The Volume instance created from the JSON data.
        """
        editor_names = json_data.get('editors')
        if editor_names:
            editor_names = editor_names.split(",")
        else:
            editor_names = []
        editors = [Editor(name=name.strip()) for name in editor_names]
        return cls(
            acronym=json_data.get('acronym'),
            title=json_data.get('title'),
            loctime=json_data.get('loctime'),
            editors=editors
        )

    def create_node(self, tx) -> int:
        """
        Create a Volume node in Neo4j.
    
        Args:
            tx: The Neo4j transaction.
    
        Returns:
            int: The ID of the created node.
        """
        query = """
        CREATE (v:Volume {acronym: $acronym, title: $title, loctime: $loctime})
        RETURN id(v) as node_id
        """
        parameters = {
            "acronym": self.acronym,
            "title": self.title,
            "loctime": self.loctime
        }
        result = tx.run(query, parameters)
        record = result.single()
        if record is not None:
            return record["node_id"]
        else:
            return None


    @staticmethod
    def load_json_file(source: str) -> List['Volume']:
        """
        Load volumes from the source JSON file.

        Args:
            source (str): Path to the source JSON file.

        Returns:
            List[Volume]: The list of loaded volumes.
        """
        with open(source, 'r') as file:
            json_data = json.load(file)

        volumes = [Volume.from_json(volume_data) for volume_data in json_data]
        return volumes
    
    @classmethod
    def default_source(cls)->str:
        """
        get the default source
        """
        default_source = os.path.expanduser('~/.ceurws/volumes.json')
        return default_source
    
    @classmethod
    def parse_args(cls,argv:list=None):
        """
        Parse command line arguments.
        
        Args:
            argv(list): command line arguments

        Returns:
            argparse.Namespace: The parsed command line arguments.
        """
        
        default_source = cls.default_source()
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Volume/Editor/Location Information")
        parser.add_argument('--source', default=default_source, help="Source JSON file path")
        # Add progress option
        parser.add_argument('--progress', action='store_true', help="Display progress information")
  
        return parser.parse_args(argv)

    @staticmethod
    def main(argv=None):
        if argv is None:
            argv=sys.argv[1:]
        args = Volume.parse_args(argv)
        volumes = Volume.load_json_file(args.source)

        # Connect to Neo4j
        driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j", "password"))
        with driver.session() as session:
            for volume in volumes:
                volume_node_id = volume.create_node(session)
                for editor in volume.editors:
                    editor.search_by_name()
                    editor.create_node(session, volume_node_id)


@dataclass
class Editor:
    """
    Represents an editor with their name and ORCID.
    """

    name: str
    orcid: str = None
    likelihood: float = None

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_data):
        """
        Create an Editor instance from JSON data.

        Args:
            json_data (dict): The JSON data representing the editor.

        Returns:
            Editor: The Editor instance created from the JSON data.
        """
        return cls(
            name=json_data.get('name'),
            orcid=json_data.get('orcid')
        )

    def search_by_name(self):
        """
        Search the editor by name using the ORCID API and calculate the likelihood.
        """
        if self.name:
            url = f"https://pub.orcid.org/v3.0/search/?q={self.name}"
            headers = {
                "Accept": "application/json"
            }
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                data = response.json()
                num_results = data.get("num-found", 0)
                self.likelihood = num_results / 10  # Arbitrary calculation, adjust as needed

    def create_node(self, tx, volume_node_id: int) -> int:
        """
        Create an Editor node in Neo4j and establish a relationship with a Volume node.
    
        Args:
            tx: The Neo4j transaction.
            volume_node_id (int): The ID of the volume node.
    
        Returns:
            int: The ID of the created Editor node.
        """
        query = """
        MATCH (v:Volume)
        WHERE id(v) = $volume_node_id
        CREATE (v)-[:HAS_EDITOR]->(e:Editor {name: $name, orcid: $orcid, likelihood: $likelihood})
        RETURN id(e) as node_id
        """
        parameters = {
            "volume_node_id": volume_node_id,
            "name": self.name,
            "orcid": self.orcid,
            "likelihood": self.likelihood
        }
        result = tx.run(query, parameters)
        record = result.single()
        if record is not None:
            return record["node_id"]
        else:
            return None



@dataclass
class Location:
    city: str
    country: str
    date: str

    @staticmethod
    def parse(location_str: str) -> Optional['Location']:
        """
        Parse a location string of the format "City, Country, Date"

        Args:
            location_str: The location string to parse.

        Returns:
            A Location object or None if the string could not be parsed.
        """
        match = re.match(r'^(.*), (.*), (.*)$', location_str)
        if match:
            city, country, date = match.groups()
            return Location(city, country, date)
        else:
            return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Volume.main()
```

**unittest**

```py
import json
from ceurws.volume_neo4j import Neo4j,Volume, Editor
from ceurws.location import LocationLookup
from tests.basetest import Basetest

class TestVolumeEditorLocation(Basetest):
    """
    Unit tests for Volume, Editor, and Location classes.
    """
    
    def setUp(self, debug=False, profile=True):
        Basetest.setUp(self, debug=debug, profile=profile)
        self.neo4j=Neo4j()
        
    def tearDown(self):
        Basetest.tearDown(self)
        self.neo4j.close()
        
    def test_neo4j_available(self):
        """
        test the port availability
        """
        for service,port in [("bolt",self.neo4j.bolt_port),("http",7474)]:
            available=Neo4j.is_port_available(self.neo4j.host, port)
            self.assertTrue(available,f"{service} service at {port}")
            
    def create_test_volume(self, year: int=2023) -> int:
        """
        Creates a test Volume node for the given year.
    
        Args:
            year (int): The year for which to create the Volume.
    
        Returns:
            int: The ID of the created Volume node.
        """
        with self.neo4j.driver.session() as session:
            with session.begin_transaction() as tx:
                acronym = f"CILC {year}"
                title = f"Proceedings of the {year-1985}th Italian Conference on Computational Logic"
                loctime = f"Some City, Italy, June 21-23, {year}"
                volume = Volume(acronym=acronym, title=title, loctime=loctime)
                volume_id = volume.create_node(tx)
            return volume_id

    def test_volume_create_node(self):
        """
        Test the create_node method of the Volume class.
        """
        volume_id=self.create_test_volume()
        self.assertIsNotNone(volume_id)
        
    def test_editor_create_editor_node(self):
        """
        Test the create_editor_node method of the Editor class.
        """
        volume_id_2023 = self.create_test_volume(2023)
        volume_id_2024 = self.create_test_volume(2024)
    
        with self.neo4j.driver.session() as session:
            with session.begin_transaction() as tx:
                # Test creating one editor for multiple volumes
                editor = Editor(name="John Doe", likelihood=0.8)
                editor_id_2023 = editor.create_node(tx, volume_id_2023)
                editor_id_2024 = editor.create_node(tx, volume_id_2024)
        
                self.assertIsNotNone(editor_id_2023)
                self.assertIsNotNone(editor_id_2024)
            
    def test_location_lookup(self):
        """
        Test the lookup method of the LocationLookup class.
        """
        location_lookup = LocationLookup()
        location = location_lookup.lookup("Amsterdam, Netherlands")
        self.assertIsNotNone(location)
        self.assertEqual(location.name, "Amsterdam")
        self.assertEqual(location.country.iso, "NL")

    def test_parse_args(self):
        """
        Test the parse_args function.
        """
        source=Volume.default_source()
        args = Volume.parse_args(["--source", source])
        self.assertEqual(args.source, source)

    def test_json_loading(self):
        """
        Test the JSON loading from a file.
        """
        with open(Volume.default_source()) as file:
            json_data = json.load(file)
        self.assertIsNotNone(json_data)
        pass
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have TLS enabled, then you need to use a different bolt [URI scheme](https://neo4j.com/docs/bolt/current/driver-api/#uri-schemes). For example, `bolt+s`.

From the docs:

> ### URI schemes
>
> ##### No TLS enabled:
>
> - `bolt`: connect to a single Neo4j instance.
> - `neo4j`: connect to a Neo4j instance and use the routing table
>   information for further connections.
>
> ##### Enable TLS and allow self-signed certificate authority:
>
> - `bolt+ssc`
> - `neo4j+ssc`
>
> ##### Enable TLS and only allow system enabled certificate authority and verify hostname:
>
> - `bolt+s`
> - `neo4j+s`

Comment: Thank you for trying to help debugging this? How would the TLS enabling happen in that environment but no in the github CI? How could i check whether TLS is enabled?

I tried your approach but bolt+ssc makes the tests fail in any case.